# AWS Linux 2 Mate Desktop Vi Pasting Issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vi, amazon-workspaces

Recently there has been issues pasting into Vi from the system clipboard.

When the text is pasted, it inserts the pasted text before the existing text on the line, rather that after the cursor position.

I've experimented with alot of different ~/.vimrc config but no joy.

OS Version

```
cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
HOME_URL="https://amazonlinux.com/"
```

Vi Version

```
vi --version |head -1
VIM - Vi IMproved 9.0 (2022 Jun 28, compiled Jun  5 2023 14:58:39)
```

Any ideas on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, it was an issue between Windows 10 Enterprise and AWS Workspaces running Linux EC2 with Mate desktop. The temp fix was to reboot Linux instance and then the Windows host. The more permanently solution is yet to be determined. So Vi / Vim is in the clear, not the issue, rather the manifestation.